# Saving the nesting level in cross-linked functions

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i have function looking through the mass of object and and push specific properties in the new massive. I want to save level of current object as the property of new object. 
(
  data[0],  data[1], ..  - level 1, 
  data[0].childs[0], data[1].childs[0], .. - level2 
  ...
)
But there are two cross linked function in my code and i blowed my head how to do that.

```js
 var data = [
 {a1: 1, a2: 2, childs: [{a1: 12, a2: 13, childs: [{a1: "test114", childs:[]}]}, {a1: 114, a2: 115, childs: [{a1:1116, a2: 1117, childs: []}]}] },
 {a1: 3, a2: 4, childs: [{a1: 22, a2: 23, childs: []}, {a1: 224, a2: 223, childs: [{a1:2221, a2: 2222, childs: []}]}] },
 {a1: 5, a2: 6, childs: [{a1: 32, a2: 33, childs: []}] },
 {a1: 7, a2: 8, childs: []}
 ];


var mass = [];
var newarray = [];
var level = 1;



function go() {
 returnObject(data, mass);
  console.log(mass);
}

function returnObject(obj, arr) {

 
 obj.forEach(function(item) {
   returnObject2(item, arr);
 });
}

function returnObject2(obj, arr){
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(arr)

  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
   return
  }

  if (obj.childs.length > 0){

   arr.push({new:obj.a1, childs: obj.childs, level: level});
   level+=1;
   return returnObject(obj.childs, arr);
  }
  else {
   return arr.push({new:obj.a1, childs: [], level: level});
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick=go()> go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make `level` a global, pass it around!

```
function returnObject(obj, arr, level) {
    obj.forEach(function(item) {
      returnObject2(item, arr, level + 1);
    });
}

function returnObject2(obj, arr, level){
   ...
   return returnObject(obj.childs, arr, level + 1);

etc
```

Comment: thanks, man. One thing, need only one (level + 1) here: return Object(obj.childs, arr, level + 1);